# data structure as a index element in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I am new to pandas and trying to learn it. I was wondering if the following can be achieved.
Say I have a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {
   'l1': [1,2,3,4],
   'm1': np.zeros((4,4)),
   's1': ["x","y","z"]
   }
```

d is dictionary with list of numbers, numpy array and a list of strings. Now say I have dictionary object like d1 for every time step(or a index). Is it possible to store object as pandas series ?

```
 t1, d1

 t2, d2

 t3, d3

 .....

 tn, dn
```

i.e. t1, t2, etc stand for the time index, and for each time index d1, d2, etc. are all dictionary of type d described above. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please type in the literal Series you want for `d`.

Comment: at every time step i am producing a dictionary like d. with different values of "l1","m1","s1". I want to save each dictionary as a time series.

Comment: just curious why was this question flagged down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store dictionaries in a DataFrame or a Series, but it's probably not the best way to go. You should rather create the dataframe with columns based on your dictionary.

```
d1 = {
   'l1': [1,2,3,4],
   'm1': np.zeros((4,4)),
   's1': ["x","y","z"]
   }

d2 = {
   'l1': [5,7,8,9],
   'm1': np.zeros((4,3)),
   's1': ["a","b","c"]
   }

df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [d1, d2]}, index=pd.date_range('2020-06-20', periods=2, freq='h'))
```